# Pine vs Birch plywood bending

Tags: plywood, wood-selection, bending

I'd like to make something like in this picture [image: backrest]

I'm thinking of using 1.2mm plywood doubled on each side. Is birch plywood (which seems to be quite a bit cheaper) any worse than pine?
If you have any tips and suggestions as to how to achieve that kind of effect, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. You can't really make something like this without specialised equipment, and if not using a press with formers lots of strong clamps — perhaps two dozen g-clamps (which would be way more costly than you might imagine)! And in either case the starting point would be neither birch nor pine plywood. Based on this how do you think you want to proceed?

Comment: Well, it seems that in this case they made it in quite a complicated way, as the front of the backrest is actually flat. I figure that the pipe above the bend is halved, and only the back bit is formed around it. Seems that the best way to achieve that is (no matter the wood, really) start with veneer of 1.0-1.5mm, soak it for an hour first, then pre-mold while drying, then glue+mold. In my case, I'd like both front and back to be wrapped around the pipe, so I'd do front and back separate, and then glue them together. The mold won't require that many clamps if made of fewer pieces.

Comment: I think you're underestimating the clamping pressure needed to first form something like this, and then to securely glue it. I'm assuming you'd use a white or yellow glue rather than some more specialist adhesive (like resorcinol) and PVAs all require *very* high clamp pressures to give the strongest bond.

Comment: I'm basing my conclusions on some YT videos, resorcinol seems like an overkill for my purpose (it's not a boat!). This guy uses https://bit.ly/2ZTS48K Titebond 3 and a few clamps. The glue is pricey, tho.
More pics of the original:
https://bit.ly/3sB5TFp

Comment: @Graphus Do correct me if you think I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Sorry I've been assuming you're also making a chair part, but that may not actually be the case — with chair parts, the whole chair actually, the tradition is to build in as much strength as possible because of the stresses chairs go thru. As for the YT link, well, beware what you get influences from! There are so many things online (and YT is perhaps the worst for this but by no means the only one) where content creators simply don't know their stuff and consistently show poor, if not actively bad, working practices. The bald truth is that *most* people underclamp with PVA, by a large margin.

Comment: Re. resorcinol, it's not that it's need for its waterproof qualities or anything, it's only that it's one of those adhesives that doesn't require high clamp pressure for strength. Should have used epoxy as the example, resorcinol was stuck in my head as it's commonly used to make plywood.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am in fact building a backrest for a chair. I know internet is full of BS advise, but soaking to pre-mold seems widespread and generally accepted. Do you know Titebond 3, and would you recommend it? Otherwise, do you see a middle-way solution that doesn't require a press or too many clamps?

Comment: Re. weak/poor/bad practices shown online, I was referring to the need for lots of clamps only.

Comment: About Titebond, I don't use it (any version) but it's undeniably a great glue and used by many true professionals who have to stand by their work, so you should have no hesitation in using it if you like its working properties. But, I do have to say that just because Titebond is the market leader in the US doesn't mean it's your best buy; alternatives could be just as good given PVA technology isn't exactly rocket science :-)